# use a controller inside a folder in the controllers folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a controller inside a folder in the controllers directory like

route

```
Route::get('/','site\HomeController@index');
```

but seem's does not work like it gives me this error

> Class App\Http\Controllers\site\HomeController does not exist

Note: I have also a HomeController.php in the controllers folder. I'm trying to organize my controllers by putting them unto their specific folders.

Any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use proper namespace, like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;
```

And add this line:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Then this route will work:

```
Route::get('/','Site\HomeController@index');
```

Comment: tried yours and it gives me this error "FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 8:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Site\Controller' not found"

Comment: I think its referring to "class HomeController extends Controller" which the "Controller" is outside the Site folder.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace of the class `HomeController` should be as:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;
```

And in your route file you can use it as:

```
Route::get('/','Site\HomeController@index');
```

Remember to add following line of code in `HomeController` class as:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Comment: tried yours and it gives me this error "FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 8:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Site\Controller' not found"

Comment: I think its referring to "class HomeController extends Controller" which the "Controller" is outside the Site folder.

Comment: In your `HomeController` class add the use statement as `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller`. Maybe it helps.